# UITextField not responding to tap

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to highlight the text in my UITextField when it is tapped by the user. The behaviour works as expected the first time I tap into the field. Once I tap out (resign first responder) and then tap back in, the text field does not regain focus unless I double-tap or long press the text field.

Here's my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
    textField.delegate = self

    // tap gesture to resign first responder 
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard(gestureRecognizer:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    // if I comment out this line or replace with a print statement, the text field regains focus on a single tap as expected        
    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
}
```

If I remove the code in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` that is responsible for selecting all text, the text field successfully regains focus on a single tap (but obviously does not highlight the text).

I tried placing a print statement in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and it doesn't get called until the double-tap or long-press when the `textField.selectedRange = ...` line is present. However, if I comment this line, then the print statement executes every time I tap into the text field.

Comment: You do realize that the feature you are trying to implement is built in? It is https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield/1619631-clearsoninsertion The selection is not visible but it’s there, so that editing and typing replaces the contents.

Comment: I have a design requirement for the selection to be visible

Comment: I've tried placing the selection code in a `DispatchQueue` block but to no avail

Comment: darn, I was about to try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it like this:

```
self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
self.textField.selectedTextRange = nil
```

Comment: I've no idea why that's needed and I don't intend to worry about it. :)

Comment: I popped that into my dismissKeyboard function and it worked perfectly. Thank you! :)